# solve for y in $c = \int_{0}^{y} \sin^n(x) dx$

Tags: integration

I'm new to Mathematica so this could be an easy question :

I'd like to solve for y  in

$$c = \int_{0}^{y} \sin^n(x) dx$$

where c and n are parameters;
n could be large $n=100$; c could be small $c=2^{-50}$ so I'm worried about numeric problems.

I tried numeric solution:

F[y_,n_]:=Module[{},a=NIntegrate[(Sin[x])^n,{x,0,y};a];

r=NSolve[F[y,n]==c,y,Reals];

the results look somewhat reasonable but a symbolic solution would be preferred.
Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Maybe this is a better location for your question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your not interested in the method to determine the result, for the integral look at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%5En+x+dx it's (not unexpectedly) difficult!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: actually I meant to put it there but somehow I picked this forum instead (poor eyesight i guess)...as it turns out the answer given is what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity let $s=\sin x$ and $c=\cos x.$ Let $V(n,x)=\int s^n\;dx.$ For $n\geq 2, $ integrate by parts: $$V(n,x)=\int s^{n-1}\; d(-c)=-c s^{n-1}+\int c\; d(s^{n-1})=-c s^{n-1}+\int (n-1)c^2 s^{n-2}\; dx=$$ $$=-c s^{n-1}+\int (n-1)(1-s^2) s^{n-2}\; dx=-c s^{n-1}+ (n-1)(V(n-2,x)-V(n,x))\; dx. $$  This implies $ n V(n,x)=$ $-c s^{n-1}+(n-1)V(n-2,x).$

Let $F(n,x,y)= \int_0^y s^n\; dx.$ So for $n\geq 2$ we have $$n F(n,x,y)= -\cos y \sin^{n-1}y +(n-1)F(n-2,x,y).$$ $$\text {So }\quad F(n,x,y)=(-1/n)\cos y \sin^{n-1}y+(n-1)/n\cdot F(x,n-2,y).$$

Answer (score 1):

To solve $$c = \int_0^y{\sin^n(x)\mathrm dx},$$
I would first use the substitution of $$\sin(x) = \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right),$$
from Euler's Formula. Substituting that in, $$c=\int_0^y{\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)}^n\mathrm dx \implies (2i)^nc=\int_0^y{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}^n\mathrm dx.$$
Using binomial expansion, this gives $$(2i)^nc=\int_0^y\sum_{k=0}^n{{n\choose k}e^{(n-k)ix}e^{-kix}}\mathrm dx \implies (2i)^nc=\int_0^y\sum_{k=0}^n{{n\choose k}e^{(n-2k)ix}}\mathrm dx.$$
Utilizing the fact that sum and integral signs can be interchanged when they don't rely on each other, 
$$(2i)^nc=\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^y{{n\choose k}e^{(n-2k)ix}\mathrm dx} \implies (2i)^nc = \sum_{k=0}^n{\left({n\choose k}\frac{e^{(n-2k)ix}}{(n-2k)i}\right)^y_{x=0}}.$$
That's as far as I got. Hope this helps!